# How do I get the object properties of an individual in SPARQL Query?

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

Suppose I give a word "Product" the results should be

```
A product ... can be ... new ... NPD
A product ... can be ... existing ... Re-design
A Product ... has ... structure, ... has ... function, ... has ... behavior
```

where "can be" and "has" are object properties and structure, function , behavior etc are the instances linked to Product

I have tried this 
[image]

I also want it to show the object properties of the output. Like here, I want it to show the object properties of Function, Behavior etc with terms other than product

Comment: Sorry, but that's unreadable. Provide the RDF data...in Turtle syntax or least N-Triples...

Comment: And then use the search engine here. This has been asked several times.

Comment: Displaying Related Individuals given Object Properties :

PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX uni:<http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?has  ?isa ?satisfies
WHERE { 
{ uni:Product uni:IsA ?isa   } 
{ uni:Product uni:Has ?has  }
{ uni:Product uni:Satisfies ?satisfies  } 

}

Comment: Now I want to get the object properties of the individuals coming as outputs in the same query itself. How do i do that ?

Comment: You're doing strange things here. Your query is syntactically wrong, have you have tried it? There is no semicolon after a PREFIX declaration, triple patterns are separated by dots and not by curly braces, ...

Comment: And next, you want to have the properties of which individuals? In your query there is a single individual called `uni:Product` for which you get several things, do you want to have the properties of those things?

Comment: There are no semicolons. Something happened here while copying. The query is working perfectly. The output of this query is different individuals related to Product. I want the object properties and related individuals of the output individuals . I want to do that in the same query itself . Is that possible ?

Comment: PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

PREFIX uni:<http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?prop  ?subject ? 
WHERE { 
{ uni:System ?prop ?subject   } 
}  In this i want to display the object properties of "subject" and its related individuals also. Again, there are no semicolons

Comment: I added an answer based on your initial SPARQL query.

Comment: Where have you added? Thanks, in advance

Comment: In the answer below.

Comment: Any idea on how to do it with the second query ?

Comment: You have to learn the principles of SPARQL, I guess. I mean you're doing graph pattern matching, i.e. `uni:System ?prop ?subject . ?subject ?p ?o .`

Comment: PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?property ?subject ?prop ?object 
WHERE {
 uni:Product ?property ?subject .
 OPTIONAL {?subject ?prop ?object }
 I tried this. Its working. But how to avoid repetitions?

Comment: What do you mean by repetition? Can you give examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the SPARQL query

```sql
PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?has ?isa ?satisfies WHERE {
 uni:Product uni:IsA ?isa .
 uni:Product uni:Has ?has .
 uni:Product uni:Satisfies ?satisfies
}
```

you can get additional information for each individual by appending another triple pattern with the variable being the subject of the triple pattern:

```sql
PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?has ?p_has ?o_has ?isa ?p_isa ?o_isa ?satisfies ?p_satisfies ?o_satisfies 
WHERE {
 uni:Product uni:IsA ?isa .
 ?isa ?p_isa ?o_isa .
 uni:Product uni:Has ?has .
 ?has ?p_has ?o_has .
 uni:Product uni:Satisfies ?satisfies .
 ?satisfies ?p_satisfies ?o_satisfies
}
```

You might have to put it into `OPTIONAL` clauses because it wouldn't return something if there is no such information:

```sql
PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
SELECT ?has ?p_has ?o_has ?isa ?p_isa ?o_isa ?satisfies ?p_satisfies ?o_satisfies 
WHERE {
 uni:Product uni:IsA ?isa .
 OPTIONAL {?isa ?p_isa ?o_isa }
 uni:Product uni:Has ?has .
 OPTIONAL {?has ?p_has ?o_has }
 uni:Product uni:Satisfies ?satisfies .
 OPTIONAL {?satisfies ?p_satisfies ?o_satisfies }
}
```